# Unable to understand use of generic interface without type parameters

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable

Here is a code of a sort class which I am implementing.

```
public class Insertion {
public static void sort(Comparable[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int temp = i;
        while (temp > 0 && less(arr[temp], arr[temp - 1])) {
            exch(arr, temp, temp - 1);
            temp--;
        }
    }
}

public static void exch(Comparable[] arr, int i, int j) {
    Comparable temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

public static boolean less(Comparable i, Comparable j) {
    return i.compareTo(j) < 0;
}}
```

Here I'm not able to understand how the comparable interface is used without type parameters.

Suppose I want to pass a class Point which implements Comparable. Here it is

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
private final int x;
private final int y;


Point(int a, int b) {
    this.x = a;
    this.y = b;
}

public int getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public int compareTo(Point p) {
    return Integer.compare(this.x, p.x);
}}
```

And here is the test code i'm testing with

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point[] pts = new Point[5];
    pts[0] = new Point(1, 2);
    pts[1] = new Point(5, 11);
    pts[2] = new Point(0, 10);
    pts[3] = new Point(1, 1);
    pts[4] = new Point(12, 3);

    Insertion.sort(pts);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        System.out.println("(" + pts[i].getX() + "," + pts[i].getY() + ")");
}}
```

So will sending `pts` in the test code make `Comparable[]` work as `Comparable<Point>[]` in the `Insertion` class.
If so then the `less()` method in Insertion class will take in two `Comparable<Point>` arguments and uses `compareTo()` from the `Point` class. But the `compareTo()` inside Point class takes in `Point` as argument. I know we can pass `Point` to `Comparable<Point>` which is runtime polymorphism I believe. But is this what's hapening?

Moreover wanted to know is there a way to parameterize this because IntelliJ shows `Raw use of parameterized class 'Comparable'`  warning.

Comment: If you are wondering how `Arrays.sort` does it look in the source code: ]https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/be44bff34df4/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java

Comment: Ohh no no...I'll remove that part..

Comment: Yes, there is a way to make it parametrized: `public static void <T> sort(Comparable<T>[] arr) { ... ` and then carry on from there.

Comment: Got the raw type part. But cannot make out this parameterization part. Will have to learn about it. What is this parameterization called? Never seen this type of method declaration. Anyway thank you soo much.

Comment: it is called generics, they can be declared on a class / interface level, but also on a method level.